# Which verses is the Vamana Purana the following quote is from?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, temple, vamana, punyam

Whoever constructs or helps to construct a Vishnu temple will protect eight generations of fathers, grandfathers, and forefathers from falling into hell.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Feel free to take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted with the site.

Answer (score 4):

This verse is found in the Vamana Purana 95.38

[पञ्चनवतितमोऽध्यायः](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%9E%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%BD%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83) - वामनपुराणम्

> पितामहस्य पुरतः कुलान्यष्टौ तु यानि च।
> तारयेदात्मना सार्धं
> विष्णोर्मन्दिरकारकः।। ९५.3८
>
> > 38. And the Eight Generations before the grandfather and his own self he reclaims who gets a temple of Vishnu constructed.
>
> E[nglish Translation](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.313087/page/536/mode/2up?view=theater) by Digital India Government Library

One may also read the Hindi translation by Gita Press Gorakhpur [from here](https://archive.org/details/vaman-puran-illustrated-with-hindi-translations-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n481/mode/2up?view=theater).

Comment: Hi! @Anagha Gopal Dasa ..., since you're new, I'd like to inform you that if the answer provided above by me is satisfactory it would be nice if you could press the tick (✔️), below the voting arrows, and accept my answer. It lets the H.SE community know that the answer satisfied your query. Thanks!